# Android, associating an xml file to an ImageView (xml file includes the rectangle coords of the Image)

Tags: android, xml, image

I have an Image that is very big and I want this image to be zoomable and include clickable areas(when clicked changes the layout or something like that). When I try to use invisible buttons for clickable areas, buttons loses their position as image being zoomed. 
I found something called imagemapping. this way you can create rectangles with coordinates and you can give id to these rects. 
example;

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<maps xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <map name="myimagename">
<area shape="rect" coords="19,34,127,160" id="@+id/area1" name = "aa"    />
<area shape="rect" coords="1331,285,1439,411" id="@+id/area2" name = "bb"    />
<area shape="rect" coords="1224,783,1332,909" id="@+id/area3" name = "cc"    />
                                         ...
                                         ...
                                         ...
</map>
</maps>
```

I believe this will be a solution to use these ids as buttons. But i cant figure how to associate my xml file to my image and display it in layout. So, please help me (:

Comment: See this: http://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/images-with-clickable-areas/

Comment: The overlay image uses different colored regions  to indicate the hotspots in this tutorial, but i have 110 regions to be clickable. This will be so hard to give 110 different colors to overlay image. But thanks anyway

Comment: I found this just now: http://catchthecows.com/?p=113

Comment: I found this yesterday, it includes a usa map an tells in a small bubble which state you tapped. I tried to add/change things to make the areas to act like buttons to change view or class but i cant succeed in that. when i add or change anything it gives a black screen, cant find and display the image. I am still working on it to figure it out. But anybody knows any other solutions please post. Thanks again @ramaral